# What's the difference between particle を and に when used for location

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

I've been learning about particles lately. As I'm still new to the language, I can't tell the difference between these two particles when used for locations for example:

> 街を歩く

Does this mean walk through town?

> 街に歩く

Does this mean walk to town?

Answer (score 5):

「街**を**歩く」means that people walks around a town and they must be inside of town. Here is another particle 「**へ**」, which is more familiar than 「**に**」 in this context. If people said that「街へ歩く」, this means that people head to a town and they probably are on their way to visit and must be outside of town.
「街に歩く」isn't a correct exression to use particle 「に」. To make it more sense with 「**に**」, I'd say 「街に向かって歩く」, which means almost the same as「街へ歩く」.

Comment: thanks for the reply but can you explain why 街に歩く　is wrong. isn’t it stating that im going directly to the town unlike the へ particle？

Comment: Yes, it means that people are going directly to the town.  Still, it sounds a  little weird. One of that reasons is that the noun 「街」 is vague and not specified place. If you say, 「海(山、学校、協会) **に**行く」, it sounds natural because I know a purpose of you going there  w/o mention.

Comment: The に used for location strongly implies a definite purpose, so 街に歩くsounds strange because you're saying something that sounds like "I go for the purpose of reaching the town", which is rather puzzling under normal circumstances.