# Which one of these sentences is more natural?

Tags: particle-で, particle-を

かれはこうえん[で]{L}さんぽします。
かれはこうえん[を]{L}さんぽします。

Which one of these sentences is more natural and why?

Comment: What are your sentences intended to mean? What does これ refer to? What's the context?

Comment: He walks in the park

Comment: Ah sorry. I need my eyes testing. I read これ rather than かれ. It's the difference between "he walks in the park" and "he walks through the park". The context would determine which was more appropriate.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/98290/%e3%82%92-vs-%e3%81%a7-for-intransitive-motion-verbs

Answer (score 1):

Please read my answer here first: [を vs. で for Intransitive Motion Verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98290/5010)

The verb さんぽする is somewhat tricky, as it falls between verbs which are almost purely about traveling (e.g., いく and あるく) and verbs which do not usually involve traveling (e.g., おどる). さんぽ definitely involves movement, but it can be done purely for health or recreation purposes. In your case, こうえん**を**さんぽします is usually more natural, but こうえん**で**さんぽします is also acceptable.

This is similar to how both プール**を**およぐ and プール**で**およぐ are correct. When you say "to swim from one end to the other of a 50-meter pool" in contexts like competitive swimming, the primary purpose is movement, so you need to use を. But when swimming for recreational purposes in a small pool, プール**で**およぐ is the correct choice.

When there is no movement involved, で should be used. For example, ジム**で**30分あるきました ("I walked for 30 minutes at the gym") is natural, but ジム**を**30分あるきました ("I walked for 30 minutes across the gym") sounds quite odd.